# Ruby, BinData, boolean not recognized as object type

Tags: ruby, bindata

The code below doesn't work, yet the type boolean exists and I used it in another class the same way, why doesn't it work here?

```
require 'bindata'
class TESTSTUFF < BinData::Record
  array  :boolstuff, :type => :boolean, :initial_length => 8
end
```

The error is: `unknown type 'boolean' in TESTSTUFF (TypeError)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such parameter as `boolean` in `bindata`. Use `bit1` that's a 1-bit big endian integer and may be used as boolean. Look at [the docs](http://bindata.rubyforge.org/).

Comment: Good to know, I made an error before (when I said I used it somewhere else, it was just an array with the same info but not used as boolean) thank you.